# In Android studio: emulator app not updating

Tags: android-studio

When I run the emulator, the app doesn't update with my changes.

I've tried rebuild and clear. But they didn't change anything.

There have been other posts here but they didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some context and examples to clarify your question. Have a look at the documenation [on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use Genymotion emulator , it always worked for me , it is always better than any emulator

https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

Answer (score 0):

Beware that the emulator of Lollipop or Jellybean doesn't auto update. I run Marshmallow (x86_64 Google APIs) on Chipmunk and it updated the app everytime I press the ▶ 'Run app' button.